# How Do I Bind Values From DropDownListFor To My Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a select control with static values in my view and I intend the user select a value and it binds to my controller so I can use it in the required action method.

My View -

```
@model StockProject.ViewModels.EquityViewModel 
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post)){    

@{
  var selectList = new SelectList(
  new List<SelectListItem>
  {
    new SelectListItem {Text = "BOOKED", Value = "1"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "EXECUTING", Value = "2"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "EXECUTED", Value = "3"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "SUSPENDED", Value = "4"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "CANCELLED", Value = "5"},
    }, "Value", "Text");
   }
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.status, selectList, new { @class = "form-control", name = "status", id = "status" })

<div class="col-md-3 form-group">                        
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block form-control" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Equity", "Order")'">
         Go
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </button>
</div>
}
```

ViewModel -

```
public class EquityViewModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }        
    public DateTime startdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime enddate { get; set; }        
    public List<ListEquityOrder> ListOrderEquity { get; set; }

    public EquityViewModel()
    {
        ListOrderEquity = new List<ListEquityOrder>();

    }
}
```

Controller -

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Equity()
{
  var modelview = new EquityViewModel();
  var model = new EquityRequest();

  model.CustomerId = _appSettings.TestCustomerId;
  model.RequestStartPoint = 0;
  model.NoOfRequests = 1000000;
  model.Null = null;
  model.Status = modelview.status; 
  model.StartDate = modelview.StartDate;
  model.EndDate =  modelview.EndDate;
  model.Equity = "EQUITY";

  EquityResponse ListEquityOrders = _genericService.CallSoapAction<EquityResponse, EquityRequest>(model, "findCustomerOrdersBySecurityType");


  List<ListEquityOrder> findCusOrder = new List<ListEquityOrder>();
  foreach (var t in ListEquityOrders.Item)
  {
    ListEquityOrder listOrder = new ListEquityOrder();

    listOrder.BusinessOffice = t.BusinessOffice;
    listOrder.CustomerLabel = t.CustomerLabel;
    listOrder.CustomerName = t.CustomerName;
    listOrder.Exchange = t.Exchange;
    listOrder.FixOrderStatus = t.FixOrderStatus;
    //adding other data values to the list

    findCusOrder.Add(listOrder);
   }
   modelview.ListOrderEquity = findCusOrder;

   return View(modelview);
 }
```

Anytime the user clicks on the submit button, no values are passed the controls - the DropDownListFor and TexBoxes. I have tried FormCollection but that doesn't work. Please how do I resolve this?

Comment: You have not shown your POST method

Comment: Your form does not have a submit button. All you have is a standard button that uses Javascript to make a GET and is not passing anything to the method

Comment: How do I implement the submit button? in razor?

Comment: Change the button to `type = "button"`. Remove the `onclick` and add a POST method in your controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm pretty new to asp.net mvc. I removed the onclick, converted the button element to <input type="button" />. If I add a [HttpPost] method with the same action name, i get an error stating another method has that name. If I change my original actionmethod to [HttpPost] all I get is a blank page when I route to that view. Can you please show me ?

Comment: Your POST method needs to have a parameter `EquityViewModel model`

Comment: I'm sorry, can I move this to the chat? I keep getting a warning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148300/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-gbade).

Comment: You don't have any submit button in your form, it contains only normal button. SO you have to write an ajax call inside your button and pass the selected dropdown value in data part of ajax and take it as a parameter in your action . Else as per Stephen Muecke's comment make button as submit and do the posting.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I added a submit button. But I still can't obtain data values from my form and pass it to the controller when I click on the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code getting the expected output.

In your model

```
public enum BookingDetails
    {
        BOOKED = 1, EXECUTING = 2, EXECUTED = 3, SUSPENDED = 4, CANCELLED = 5
    }

    public class SomeModel
    {
        public BookingDetails bookingDetails { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetBookingDetailsSelectItems()
        {
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "BOOKED", Value = "1" };
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "EXECUTING", Value = "2" };
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "EXECUTED", Value = "3" };
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "SUSPENDED", Value = "4" };
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "CANCELLED", Value = "5" };
        }
    }
```

Note : The above model only deals with dropdown values. If you want to do more then fell free to extend the class

Then your controller should be like below

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        // GET: My
        public ActionResult MyAction()
        {
            // shows your form when you load the page
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyAction(SomeModel model)
        {

            var selectedBookingDetails = model.bookingDetails;// this will be the selected dropdown item text.

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

then view

```
@model SomeModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "My", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.bookingDetails, SomeModel.GetBookingDetailsSelectItems())
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

Note : please include the correct namespace of model